# How to check output in terminal in production

Tags: terminal, pm2

i have a project serving on production which use pm2 to handle my nodejs server. How could i to check the bash output? Because i need to debug what's wrong in production, and it work in local machine. Which server is serve from digitalOcean.

Appreciate for your command.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the stdout or stderr (bash output) of a pm2-run project with `pm2 logs`

Read the [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#displaying-logs) for more details

Comment: If this worked for you. Remember you can mark it as an answer and help others looking for the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Use can use logger to records all the changes along with various methods such as warning, error or info